# TinyMCE Image uploading

Tags: javascript, php, html, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE for our website. I am trying to get images in the editor.

However, I cannot seem it get it working as I want to.

I have looked around but cannot find a code that works for me. If it is our code or by my doing, I cannot seem to find it working properly.

Here is the code I use:

```
<textarea id="my_editor"></textarea>

<iframe id="form_target" name="form_target" style="display:none"></iframe>

<form id='my_form' action='/upload/' target='form_target' method='post'     enctype='multipart/form-data' style='width:0 px;height:0 px;overflow:hidden'>
<input name='image' type='file' onchange="$('#my_form').submit();this.value='';"></form>
```

I am using this to load the javascript files:

```
$jsFiles = array(
        $templatePath . 'js/jquery.js',
        $templatePath . 'tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js'
    );
    foreach ($jsFiles as $file) {
        echo '<script src="' . $file . '"></script>' . "\r\n        ";
    }
    ?>
```

And the javascript for TinyMCE itself:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#my_editor',
        plugins: ["image"],
        file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {
            win.document.getElementById(field_name).value = 'my_editor';
            if(type=='image') $('#my_form input').click();
        }
    });
    </script>
```

This is how it ends up:
[image: This is how it ends up]

The button itself works but does not pick the images either.

A solution, alternative or anything else is appreciated.